# JQuery and foreach loops

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i have this code .. but with small problem .. i want to get some information about each module when i show the hidden tr .. i will get the information from the page {modules/$moduleid} .. i know how to use ajax .. but my problem is how to use the variable {$module.id} in the javascript code to give it the url of information page !

this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.subjects').click(function(){  
 var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
$tr.nextUntil('.module-row').fadeIn(2000);
});

 $('.result').click(function(){  
 $(this).fadeOut(2000);
});
});
</script>
<br /><br /><table width="100%">
<tr class="tbl">
<td colspan="6">{$ci->lang->line('modules_list')}</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="tbl1" style="width: 8%;">{$ci->lang->line('number')}</td>
<td class="tbl2" style="width: 28%;">{$ci->lang->line('title')}</td>
<td class="tbl1" style="width: 10%;">{$ci->lang->line('add_subject')}</td>
<td class="tbl2" style="width: 10%;">{$ci->lang->line('subjects_list')}</td>
<td class="tbl1" style="width: 8%;">{$ci->lang->line('edit')}</td>
<td class="tbl2" style="width: 8%;">{$ci->lang->line('delete')}</td>
</tr>
{foreach $modules_list as $module}
<tr class="module-row">
<td class="tbl1" style="width: 8%;">{$module.number}</td>
<td class="tbl2" style="width: 28%;">{$module.title}</td>
<td class="tbl1" style="width: 10%;"><a href="{base_url('admincp/subjects/add')}/{$module.id}"><img src="{base_url('images/icons/add.png')}" /></a></td>
<td class="tbl2" style="width: 10%;"><img style="cursor: url;" class="subjects" src="{base_url('images/icons/list.png')}" /></td>
<td class="tbl1" style="width: 8%;"><a href="{base_url('admincp/modules/edit')}/{$module.number}"><img src="{base_url('images/icons/edit.png')}" /></a></td>
<td class="tbl2" style="width: 8%;"><a onclick="return confirm('{$ci->lang->line('delete_confirm_msg')}')" href="{base_url('admincp/modules/delete')}/{$module.number}"><img src="{base_url('images/icons/delete.gif')}" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="result" style="display:none">
<td colspan="7">
RESULT
</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

for example this is the code i use to get the subjects of each module :

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "../subjects/module_select/$module_id",
    type : "POST",
    data : dataAll,
    dataType :"html",
    success : function(msg){
       $('#select_subject').fadeIn(1000);
         $('#select_subject').html(msg)

    }
```

now how can i assign $module_id every time in the loop !

Comment: Where does $module_id appear in your markup? I don't see it.

Comment: Put it in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: it is assigned but i don't have to show it . i just only want to get some information from database with the id .. i prefer to use ajax to get this data but i don't know how to input the $module_id in javascript code to redirect ajax to modules/$module_id :S

Comment: would you explain it in a better way?

Comment: i have a list of modules comes from database .. every module have subjects under it .. i want to get the list of subjects of each module by ajax once clicking on (subjects) img .. subjects list are shown in ( subjects/$module_id ) page

problem is i don't know how to put $module_id variable in ajax url .. especially that i'm using loops :(

Comment: But where is `$module_id`? Is it the value of a data attribute on the image element you click on?

Comment: nope , it's already assigned each time in loop it gives the id column in database

Comment: but i didn't print it in the table . just want to use it in the javascript code

Comment: oh sorry . i meant ($module.id) not $module_id ..

Comment: {$module.id} is like {$module.number} and {$module.title} in the loop .. each <tr> contains new value and so on .. each module has an id i can print it with {$module.id} .. i just want to use that id to get some information from database by using JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a mistake to not include the id in the table. Here I've added $module_id to the data-id attribute of a *hidden* div. This id is then assigned to `moduleId`, and you can then use that in your JS code any way you like.

```
#module_id { display: none; }

<div id="module_id" data-id="$module.id"></div>

var moduleId = $('#module_id').data('id');

$.ajax({
  url: "../subjects/module_select/" + moduleId
});
```

Even better would be to add it to the `data-id` attribute on the element that' catching your click event, whatever that is.

```
<tr data-id="$module.id" class="module-row">

$(document).on('click', '.module-row', function () {
  var moduleId = $(this).data('id');
  // Do ajax
});
```